# Java Quicksort why / where do the values change?

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm learning Java in school right now and our latest topic are sort algorithms in Java. The one that I'm trying to understand is quicksort.

To understand how that algorithm sorts numbers in an array I decided to go through my code step for step in the Eclipse debugger window.

Now there was one step that I can not comprehend even after going through it what felt like hundreds of times.

My initial array is `[10, 5, 3, 22, 11, 2]`

When I go through the code the program starts by swapping `10` and `2`, then `5` and `3` and then `2` and `2`. At that point the value for `i` is `1` and the value for `j` is `-1`.

Now the way I see it is that there are three conditions

1. `while(i<=j)` Which returns `false`, because `i = 1` and `j = -1`
2. `if(left < j)` Which returns `false`, because `left = 0` and `j = -1`
3. `if(i < right)` Which also returns `false`, because `i = 1` and `right = 1`

But to my surprise when the program gets to the last bracket right before `public static void display` the program skips back to line 40 `if(i < right)`
but suddenly the values for `right`, `i`, `j` and `pivot` have changed from to `5`, `2`, `-1`, and `3` respectively.

I would be **very** grateful if someone could explain why the values get changed.

I have also added two pictures which show what I see on my Eclipse window [step I don't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu8CO.jpg)

```
public class QSort {

    public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int left, int right){
        int i = left;
        int j = right;
        int temp;
        int pivot = arr[(left+right)/2];
        System.out.println("\n\nleft = " + left + "\tright = " + right);
        System.out.println("Pivot is: " + pivot + "(" +  (left+right)/2 + ")");
        while(i <= j){
            while(arr[i] < pivot){
                System.out.println("i is: " + arr[i] + "(" + i + ")");
                i++;
                System.out.println("i is: " + arr[i] + "(" + i + ")");
            }
            while(arr[j] > pivot){
                System.out.println("j is: "+ arr[j] + "(" + j + ")");
                j--;
                System.out.println("j is: "+ arr[j] + "(" + j + ")");
            }
            if(i <= j){
                System.out.println("i is: " + arr[i] + "(" + i + ")");
                System.out.println("j is: "+ arr[j] + "(" + j + ")");
                System.out.println("Swapped " + arr[i] + "(" + i + ")"+ " with " + arr[j] + "(" + j + ")");
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
                System.out.println("i is: (" + i + ")");
                System.out.println("j is: (" + j + ")");
                System.out.println("Pivot is: " + pivot + "(" +  (left+right)/2 + ")");
            }
        }
        if(left < j){
            System.out.println("j is: (" + j + ")");
            quickSort(arr, left, j);
        }
        if(i < right){
            System.out.println("i is: (" + i + ")");
            quickSort(arr, i, right);
        }
    }

    public static void display(int[] arr){
        if(arr.length > 0){
            System.out.print(arr[0]);
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
            System.out.print(", " + arr[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] data = new int[]{10,5,3,22,11,2};
        System.out.println("Before: ");
        display(data);
        quickSort(data, 0, data.length-1);
        System.out.println("\nAfter: ");
        display(data);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to have a sneek @[Java Implementation of Quick Sort](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4022/java-implementation-of-quick-sort)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you don't fully understand recursion. At least that's what it sounds like from your desription of the question.

Anyway, I've tried to simply follow your program by keeping a trace of all variables. Hope this helps:

```
arr                 left       right      i         j      pivot
-----------------   -------    --------   -------   -----  ----------
[10,5,3,22,11,2]    0          5         
                                          0         5      arr[2] = 3
[2,5,3,22,11,10]                          1         4
                                                    3
                                                    2
[2,3,5,22,11,10]                          2         1
```

The while loop has finished because `i<=j` is now `false` (`2 > 1`).

The first condition `left < j` (`0 < 1`) is `true`, so you call `quicksort` again recursively: `quicksort(arr, 0, 1)` - which means you now sort the array `[2,3]` which is already sorted, so nothing will happen:

```
arr                 left       right      i         j      pivot
-----------------   -------    --------   -------   -----  ----------
[2,3,5,22,11,10]    0          1
                                          0         1      arr[0] = 2
                                                    0
[2,3,5,22,11,10]                          1         -1
```

The while loop condition is now `false`. The first condition `left < j` is `false` as well (because `0 > -1`) and the second condition `i < right` is also false (because `1 == 1`) So this call is finished and you return to where you were. Were was that? The first condition of the table above. The state of variables and parameters is now:

```
arr                 left       right      i         j      pivot
-----------------   -------    --------   -------   -----  ----------
[10,5,3,22,11,2]    0          5         2          1      3
```

The second condition is checked (as it is the next line executed). Its value is also true since the condition is `i < right` (`2 < 5`). So you now do `quicksort` again recursively: `quicksort(arr, 2, 5)` - which means you now sort the array `[3,22,11,10]`:

```
arr                 left       right      i         j      pivot
-----------------   -------    --------   -------   -----  ----------
[2,3,5,22,11,10]         2          5         
                                          2         5      arr[3] = 22
                                          3
[2,3,5,10,11,22]                          4         4
                                          5
```

`i > j` now so we exit the while loop.

The first condition `left < j` (`2 < 4`) is `true`, so we call `quicksort(arr, 2, 4)` in order to sort `[5,10,11]` which is already sorted. I'll skip this part as it does not change the array at all.

When the recursive call is done, we return to where we were and now the second condition will be checked. `i < right` (`5 < 5`) is `false` And so we're done.

The original `quicksort` call has finished and the array is sorted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts, this made it very easy to understand for me. And you were right i had not understood how recursion works. I thought when we call another quicksort the "main" quicksort stops and is done working. =)

Answer (score 2):

The first picture you have shows the debugger is inside two recursive invocations of quicksort: quicksort is called from main, and then on line 38 calls quicksort again (this is the principle of quicksort, it's a recursive strategy). So you see you're on line 40 of the inner call, then when you step from there, you go back to the previous invocation of quicksort (the debugger shows you a stack of two lines instead of three in the top left window), and you're back to the previous values of pivot, etc. The array is passed as is to all recursive invocations so it's shared, but the integer variables aren't.

I think here it's the recursion that makes it hard to understand, check your call stack.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was also the first time i used the eclipse debugger and i wasn't quite sure about what all these things meant. Didn't know the program jumped back to the previous invocation of quicksort :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your efforts of studying a sorting algorithms using print statements and a debugger are commendable! But your current implementation of Quicksort is rather difficult to understand, at least initially, because it has got both iteration and recursion going on (i.e. you use loops and at the same time, you have a procedure `quicksort` calling itself).

Let's take a rather different approach (purely recursive approach) to see how [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) works and why it works. Converting this recursive procedure to an iterative one (somewhat like you have written) is, luckily, a matter of technique (in this case)! I propose we do this here because that way we might control the complexity better. **Again, the reason I am doing this is to better understand what is going on**.

When Sir Tony Hoare proposed the algorithm and proved its correctness, it was something like this:

```
  public static void qsort(int[] ints, int fi, int li) {                           
    /* the recursive procedure */                                                  
    if (fi < li) {                                                                 
      int p = partition(ints, fi, li); // key routine -- see below                                           
      qsort(ints, fi, p - 1);                                                      
      qsort(ints, p + 1, li);                                                      
    }                                                                              
  }
```

That's it! Isn't beautiful? Well, it is. All you do is:

- *Partition* the given array. In my eyes, partitioning is an elegant procedure to solve a tricky problem well. The problem is simple: Given an array of numbers, *rearrange* the array such that there is a number in it, all the numbers to the left of which are smaller or equal to it and all the numbers to the right of which are larger than or equal to it -- return the index of such an element in the array. I urge you to try to solve this problem on your own. Both the procedures (Lomuto and Hoare) given on Wikipedia work well.
- Once you are sure that your partitioning works as expected, you *recursively* sort the two partitions using the same `qsort` procedure (the order of recursive calls does *not* matter) **and you are done**!

I tried to implement the `partition` procedure myself:

```
/**
  Implements partitioning of array a from a[p] to a[r], leaves all the other elements of the array intact.
  @param a the given int array
  @param p int first index of the part of array to be partitioned
  @param r int the second index of the part of array to be partitioned
*/
  public static int partition(int[] a, int p, int r) {
    //this is something I have written
    int pivot = a[p];
    int i = p + 1;
    int j = i - 1;
    while (i <= r) {
      if (a[i] < pivot) {
        a[j] = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j+1];
        j++;
      }
      i++;
    }
    a[j] = pivot;
    return j;
  }

  private static void swap(int[] ints, int i1, int i2) {
    int tmp = ints[i2];
    ints[i2] = ints[i1];
    ints[i1] = tmp;
  }
```

Now, I haven't yet proved the *correctness* of this procedure, but we can do that separately. You can even reimplement the [Lomuto procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) and see that it works to your satisfaction.

And that's it. If you now want to debug this with a debugger, you are more than equipped to do it. Here's the [entire implementation](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/e28cbcb02654903c2d90).

**Now, the question of converting this recursive procedure to an iterative one is very interesting and this document: (shameless plug: I wrote it) [http://bit.ly/recurse-iterate](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1T_Gmno5NiqLJDeFqzHd17kUQewecjtJzqNb9eSWeEYQ/edit#) should give you some clues**. Actual conversion of the above Quicksort procedure to an iterative one is left as an exercise to the reader :-).

Comment: I have to admit i did not write all that code myself except for the print statements, i used it as an example to understand how Quicksort works in Java. Thank you for your additional information and suggestions I will definetly check it out. Thanks :)